# aws opsworks chef, git cloning

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, chef-infra

I am using AWS opworks chef to test out deployment features and what not.
I have local git server/repo on the network and i am simply trying to clone a repo to a directory within the instance from that server. I saw that chef has a resource for git,so in turn i added this to my recipe:

```
git 'test_deploy' do
      repository 'http://git@192.0.0.10/scm/in/test.git'
      revision 'master'
      action :sync
      destination '/home/ubuntu'   
 end
```

When Opsworks has finished, the instance is 'online' with no errors in the console output :

```
[2016-09-19T13:37:01+00:00] INFO: Processing git[test_deploy] action sync (test::default line 38)
[2016-09-19T13:37:02+00:00] INFO: Chef Run complete in 10.401210434 seconds
```

For a couple days now i had issues trying to get SSH working which to no avail and did not worked, so to tried and go around this i just used HTTP instead and made the repo public(to stop ssh prompt) to see if i can get anything on the instance when the 'setup' phase has been issued through opworks.

Considering there are no errors and when i log into the instance, no source code has been clone to the home user directory??? not sure how to debug this.
Can anyone help me out here on what i am doing wrong, i dunno why its so finicky to just clone something??

PS the chef git resource documentation where that helpful for me (unless i am missing something here) kinda sad there are no clear examples. i did run ruby -c against my rb files to check the sytax which is all good

Any advice will be must appreciated

Comment: I wanted to add when i do a normal "git clone http://git@192.0.0.10/scm/in/test.git" (http:// infront) that works on the instance , also the repo server is a test bitbucket server

Comment: Try `git clone http://git@192.0.0.10/scm/in/test.git /home/ubuntu` to have the same behavior as what you're asking chef to do.

Comment: That is interesting as the above doesnt work with the "/home/ubuntu" at the end of git clone "http://git@192.0.0.10/scm/in/test.git" I am wondering if i should leave the destination attribute blank seeing it is trying to hit the home directory and see if that works? going to try now

Comment: Nope, just give a directory after. If you remove the destination property it becomes the name of the resource (test_deploy here) and will write somewhere (chef cache or the current directory when chef is launched, I can't tell)

Comment: Yes that works, hmmm im gunna try leaving the '' destination'' blank, if that doesnt work i will try put a random directory and see, trying now

Comment: @Tensibai adding '/home/ubuntu/test' actually worked :O argh! instead of just doing '/home/ubuntu'  this is very subtle it seems, as in the chef aws opworks console it did not actually display the **git** fatal error of 'directory already exist'. Rather, it just says the message above stating it executed/ran the git resource successfully.so painful. Also i assumed the git clone would create the folder it needs to put the source like the usual process. But thankyou for looking at it different way, this problem did catch me out partly cos the chef aws console didnt display that error.

Comment: @Tensibai , would you happen to know how to implement ssh ??

Comment: IIRC opsworks is a modified version of chef, I do think a git resource would fail the run with a 'standard' chef. For the ssh part, I can't guess how your network/vpc is articulated and what your security groups are, so it's hard to tell what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the answer to the initial problem below:

> @Tensibai adding '/home/ubuntu/test' actually worked :O argh! instead of just doing '/home/ubuntu' this is very subtle it seems, as in the chef aws opworks console it did not actually display the git fatal error of 'directory already exist'. Rather, it just says the message above stating it executed/ran the git resource successfully.so painful. Also i assumed the git clone would create the folder it needs to put the source like the usual process. But thankyou for looking at it different way, this problem did catch me out partly cos the chef aws console didnt display that error.